# AngularFire $add operation cause the browser to freeze

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am learning Firebase using angularjs. From this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angularfire-realtime-slack-clone/creating-the-channels-sidebar, the code used to add a new chat room is like this

```
channels.$add(vm.newRoom).then(function (ref) {
```

However, when i run the application, this $add operation successfully add a new record in firebase table but it also causes the whole browser to freeze.

Angular version: 1.6.2
Firebase: 3.7.1
AngularFire: 2.1.0

Comment: Is there any console error  ?

Comment: It just shows a dialog saying the script is busy. In the console log, it shows "Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
$$resolve@http://localhost:55481/Scripts/angular.js". I notice that it never gets into the then callbacks

Comment: Duplicated and answered here: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/924

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in Firebase 3.7.1. When I reverted to Firebase 3.7.0 my code works and my browsers don't freeze. I've reported the bug to Firebase.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so too and I downgraded the firebase version and it worked

Comment: Firebase 3.6.10 worked for me even though angularfire 2.3.0 requires firebase 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

This was recently fixed in Firebase 3.8.0. Recommend upgrading instead of reverting at this point!