# AngularFire simple example freezes Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to implement a simple chat example using Angular and Firebase. It works well on Safari, but it freezes Chrome and Firefox (running on local or remote base). Does anyone have some clue on what's wrong on my code? Thanks for any help!

```
<html ng-app="ZzzzApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('ZzzzApp',['firebase']);

        app.controller("ChatController", function($scope, $firebaseArray){  
            var config = {
               apiKey: "AIzaSyA8nk5dSF8HKUSQr_2H04hwTRZ2NWDwSOE",
               authDomain: "chattest-9fe81.firebaseapp.com",
               databaseURL: "https://chattest-9fe81.firebaseio.com",
               storageBucket: "chattest-9fe81.appspot.com",
               messagingSenderId: "353125975278"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);

            var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('12345');
            $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

            $scope.addMessage = function(){
                $scope.messages.$add({direction: 'S', message: $scope.messageToSend});
                $scope.messageToSend = '';
            };   
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ChatController">    
        <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <p>{{message.message}}</p>
        </div>      
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='messageToSend'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='addMessage()'>Send</button>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing an `ng-app` on your `body` tag: `<body ng-app="ZzzzApp">`. See a working example here: http://jsbin.com/qucomu/edit?html,js,output. That example works fine in Chrome 56 for me.

Comment: Tnx for helping me, ng-app can be located at HTML tag, as I did. I notice my script works when it runs from inside StackOverflow, but it freezes when running locally. I tried your example, but it seems to have no permission to write on firebase, so I pointed to my database and got it freezing again.

Comment: You indeed don't have write permissions to the database in my example. But the read-operation works. What specific action is giving problems in our local setup. Please provide a [**minimal** complete reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): if reads are not the cause, don't include them in the repro.

Comment: Thank again, you are right, I don't have reading problems, the problem occurs on addMessage function. New registers are perfectly added to Firebase, but the script freezes after saving data without leaving any clue, no console messages, no javascript errors, no traffic... You can use my script locally to reproduce the error, my database is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like that's a bug in Firebase ^3.7.1. Had the same issue and came across another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744945/angularfire-add-operation-cause-the-browser-to-freeze). Try specifying Firebase version:

`dependencies: {
    "firebase": "3.7.0",
    "angularfire": "^2.3.0"
    ...
}`

Comment: It looks like this same issue is covered in Github under https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/924. I'd recommend tracking there for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong - how is your data structured?

Try change the addMessage function like this:

```
$scope.addMessage = function(){
    $scope.messages.$add({direction: 'S', message: $scope.messageToSend})
    .then(() => $scope.messageToSend = '')
};
```

Just to be sure you only empty the messageToSend, after it successfully have been added to the firebase array. Any output in your console?

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are no error on console, it's driving me crazy. This code is functional, save and run it locally to see the problem by yourself.